# Excel, Check 3 Sheets and Display Pricing of Same Item on Sheet 4

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have product pricing from 3 different systems (in 3 different sheets) and I'm trying to display the different product pricing per system in the 4th Sheet.

[image: screenshot]

If a Product ID is missing from one of the systems the price for that system would be Null/False or a 0.

The goal is to find pricing discrepancies and missing products.

I've Googled it for a long time and can't find the right answer. THANK YOU FOR YOUR HELP!

Comment: Use VLOOKUP wrapped in IFERROR()  so `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(...),"Null")`  Where `...` is the 4 criteria needed for the VLOOKUP.  Make sure the forth criteria is `FALSE`

Comment: Thank you for your reply Scott, but that did work for me.

Comment: Please post the formula you tried in the original post using edit.

Comment: What did you try? What is not working?

Answer (score 0):

vlookup works if the criteria is in first column use

For sheet1:
vlookup(lookup_value,Table,offset,match_type)

Lookup_value is the criteria , productID in this caase

Table Range where to look e.g  sheet1!A2:f1000

Column No.   if your product name in column d then it would be 4

match_type would be false

If your productID  is not in the first column then use index function.

if you can upload a snapshot then it will be batter

Thanks